# Place view on top of others SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui

Please before closing my question, note that I already know of `.offset`, but I just can't find the right way to use it.

I'm developing a simple Music App in SwiftUI, and I'd like to, as shown in the image below, place a simple navigation bar on top of an image, that at the same time is covering a good part of the screen. To achieve this I used `.offset` and placed it on `(UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 2) * -1` so that it is on top, but this only resulted in really weird behavior of other elements such as scroll views not working, elements clipping each other, etc.

[image]

Is there any cleaner and better way to achieve this? Am I using `.offset()` wrong?

**Thanks in advance**

**My Code**

**ContentView.swift**

```
import SwiftUI

enum SelectedView: Int, CaseIterable {
    case liked = 0
    case recent = 1
    case top = 2
}

struct MenuView: View {

    @State var selectedView: SelectedView

    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Spacer()

            MenuButton(view: .liked, isSelected: false)

            Spacer()

            MenuButton(view: .recent, isSelected: false)

            Spacer()

            MenuButton(view: .top, isSelected: false)

            Spacer()
        }.foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "inversedAdaptiveColor")!))
        .font(.headline)

        .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 100)
                    .frame(height: 80)
                .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor(named: "adaptiveColor")!))
        )
    }

    func getSelectedView(x: SelectedView) -> MenuButton {


        if x == selectedView {
            return MenuButton(view: x, isSelected: true)
        } else {
            return MenuButton(view: x, isSelected: false)
        }


    }

}

struct MenuButton: View {

    let view: SelectedView

    @State var isSelected: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.isSelected.toggle()
        }) {
            if view == .liked {
                Text("Liked")
                .overlay( isSelected ?
                        AnyView (
                            Circle()
                                .frame(width: 5, height: 5)
                        .padding(.top, 40))
                        : AnyView(Spacer())
                )
            } else if view == .recent {
                Text("Recent")
                .overlay( isSelected ?
                        AnyView (
                            Circle()
                                .frame(width: 5, height: 5)
                        .padding(.top, 40))
                        : AnyView(Spacer())
                )
            } else {
                Text("Top")
                .overlay( isSelected ?
                        AnyView (
                            Circle()
                                .frame(width: 5, height: 5)
                        .padding(.top, 40))
                        : AnyView(Spacer())
                )
            }
        }
    }

}

struct HomeView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            TopMainView()
            Spacer()
            ScrollView {
                MenuView(selectedView: .liked)
                    .padding(.vertical, 50)
                SongView(title: "Doesn't Matter", author: "Akon", artwork: "misician2", darkInterface: false, type: .outside)
                SongView(title: "Doesn't Matter", author: "Akon", artwork: "misician2", darkInterface: false, type: .outside)
                SongView(title: "Doesn't Matter", author: "Akon", artwork: "misician2", darkInterface: false, type: .outside)
            }.padding().padding(.top, -150)
                .frame(height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 2) - 200)
            NowPlayingView()
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)

    }
}

struct TopMainView: View {

    @State var opacity: Double = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           Image("misician2")
            .resizable()
            .frame(height: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 2) - 20)
            .cornerRadius(50, corners: [.bottomLeft, .bottomRight])
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

            TransparentNavigationView(view: .home)
                .padding(.horizontal, 30)
                .offset(y: (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height / 2) * -1)

        }
    }
}

struct HomeView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        HomeView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you provide your problem code?

Comment: do you also show us your transparentnavigationview? it is always a good idea to show us code, which is runnable, reproduces the problem and compilable....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI uses `ZStack{}` for layered views.

Here’s a good primer: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-layer-views-on-top-of-each-other-using-zstack

I’m sorry it’s nearly 1am here and I don’t have time now for a more thorough answer, but I see you’re active 3min ago, and that should point you in the right direction.